# Android adb devices does not detect my phone

Tags: android, adb, windows-8.1, samsung-galaxy

I have Android Studio on Windows 8.1 and I want to run my android app on my Samsung Galaxy S7 phone.

Here are the details:

1. USB debugging in my phone is ON
2. adb version is 1.0.36
3. Under Device Manger -> Portable Devices -> My Phone, the status is 'The device is working properly'
4. I also installed Google USB driver in SDK Tools
5. My desktop can detect my phone since I can read and write files using Windows Explorer

I tried the following but still, adb devices still does not recognize my phone.

1. Tried USB Configuration MTP
2. Tried USB Configuration PTP
3. Tried using different USB cables
4. Tried restarting Android Studio before and after I plug my device to my desktop

Did I miss any configuration? Any help is appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: What kind of USB cable are you using? Some cheap cables are only suitable for charging and are missing the data line, but that might be disqualified by detail #5...

Comment: After re-reading... have you tried `adb kill-server` followed by `adb start-server` ?

Comment: I used the USB cable that came with the Samsung phone and I also used a USB cable from my HTC phone. Both did not work. Also tried adb kill-server and adb start-server while the phone is connected to my desktop but it still did not work.

Comment: when connected to the USB port be sure to switch to **charge only**

Comment: plug out and plug in the usb (assuming you have usb debugging enabled )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

install drivers for your device and enable developer mode for your device

Comment: Google USB driver are you talking about this driver?...this won't work for you.....u need to get samsung drivers installed

Comment: when connected to the USB port be sure to switch to **charge only**

Comment: @Mike You saved my day!

Comment: @lionscribe Happy Android!

Answer (score 4):

I too had the same problem.
I tried the following and it worked.

Make sure Developer options and USB debugging is enabled on your device
Then on your Windows system.

1. Open device manager and locate your device's ADB Interface Driver
2. Right click and choose properties
3. Check in the general tab if your device is working properly
4. If it is not enabled then go to Driver tab and select enable
5. You may have to try enabling your device a few times(7-8)

If this works then you may see the below message on the General tab

```
This device is working properly.
You need to restart your computer before the changes you made to this device will take effect.
```

And that's how I made it work.

Comment: Please use comment if you have any suggestion related the question if you post an answer then,  Please see this first [how-to-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 2):

While the simple answer here is enable debug mode and install drivers, I think the answer should mention that if nothing works , do install google drivers. I stumbled on a video explaining the same, so adding the link here.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=asbkkV-IIZc

It helped fix my issue with oneplus device. Also, I could get the google usb drivers from android studio > sdk manager > sdk tools section.

Hoping to save someone else's time.

Answer (score 0):

If you entered command `adb devices` in cmd and don't see your device ID, you can to open Windows Task Manager and close adb.exe task. Then you need to open again cmd and enter `adb start-server` and check devices again.

If you don't see your device ID after all then maybe problem in phone or drivers.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer [here](http://ivanrf.com/en/adb-driver-and-windows-8-1/)

I just need to install Samsung USB driver and it worked fine. I guess the Google USB driver did not work for me.

Also, I didn't know that I need to install a USB driver even if I can already read/ write files to my phone when I connect it to my desktop.

In Device Manager, I was looking at the wrong device (Portable Devices). I should have been looking at Other devices and there I can see that the Samsung phone has no drivers installed.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Just try another USB port on your computer.

Answer (score 0):

rebooting of the android device worked for me. Also, try to use the port USB 2.0

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same issue on my MAC-OS. Restarting the MAC fixed the issue.

I also installed Android File Transfer to check if this was only a debugging issue or if it was an issue  with the connected devices. Even AFT wasn't working  so it was definitely not a debugging issue.

I also got this message on launching Studio  after restarting the MAC. [image]

Answer (score 0):

sometimes windows firewall prohibit the adb.exe in platform-tolls folder

1. first check your phone and be sure about "usb debugging" is "on"
2. check that Default USB configuration is on "transferring files"
3. if you checked 1,2 but the problem is not solved you should reinstall platform-tools from "SDK manager" then "SDK tools" uncheck "Android SDK platform-tools" click apply then reinstall it by check "Android SDK platform-tools"
   [image]

Answer (score 0):

Guys actual issue phone was not detected by laptop, android in charging point data bus was gone bad after replacing the phone charging point type -c upon repair it started working.